# Kusto query to calculate % of the total by dcount()

Tags: kql

I’m newbie in Kusto language and I am trying to create a query that calculates the percentage of the total at the unique user level. the ratio column doesn't return any result-  maybe I'm doing it wrong :/ is there a better way to do this?

```
let T2 = T1 
|where timesstamp >ago(1m) and variable =='ss'
|summarize col_1 = dcount(user) by bin(timesstamp, 1s)
;
let T3 = T1
|where timesstamp >ago(1m) and variable in ('ss', 'ss1', 'ss2', 'ss3')
|summarize col_2 = dcount(user) by bin(timesstamp, 1s)
;
T3
| join T2 on timesstamp
|extend ratio =tolong(col_1/col_2)*100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
let T1 = datatable(timestamp:datetime, variable:string, user:string)
[
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:35), "ss", "u1",
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:35), "ss1", "u1",
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:35), "ss2", "u1",
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:35), "ss2", "u2",
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:36), "ss", "u2",
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:37), "ss", "u2",
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:37), "ss", "u1",
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:37), "ss2", "u1",
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:37), "ss1", "u2",
    datetime(2020-09-03 03:14:37), "ss3", "u3",
]
;
let T2 = T1 
    | where timestamp > ago(10m) and variable == 'ss'
    | summarize col_1 = dcount(user) by bin(timestamp, 1s)
;
let T3 = T1
    | where timestamp > ago(10m) and variable in ('ss', 'ss1', 'ss2', 'ss3')
    | summarize col_2 = dcount(user) by bin(timestamp, 1s)
;
T3
| join T2 on timestamp
| project timestamp, col_1, col_2, ratio = round(100.0 * col_1 / col_2, 2)
```

--->

```
| timestamp                   | col_1 | col_2 | ratio |
|-----------------------------|-------|-------|-------|
| 2020-09-03 03:14:35.0000000 | 1     | 2     | 50    |
| 2020-09-03 03:14:36.0000000 | 1     | 1     | 100   |
| 2020-09-03 03:14:37.0000000 | 2     | 3     | 66.67 |
```